# How to do in-order traversal of a BST without recursion or stack but using parent pointers?

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, iteration, inorder

Is it possible to do an iterative in-order-traversal on a BST whose node has a parent pointer (the parent of the root is `null`) without using a `visited` flag or a `stack`?

I googled and didn't find a reply. The point is, how can I know - at a certain node - that I've just come to it vs I've finished everything underneath it?

Comment: Recursion? Though thats an indirect use of stacks.

Comment: This sounds like one of those silly interview questions. Recursion is most likely the expected answer.

Comment: [@Shubham, @pablochan] If you read the question again, you'll find the word *iterative* written explicitly.

Comment: Well then the answer is no (unless you can save the visited nodes somewhere)

Comment: @pablochan, are you sure? I think you can do that, see my answer.

Comment: @svick: I made the comment before you answered. Apparently I was wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do that, you just need to remember the last visited node along with the current node. Doing this is not disallowed by the problem statement: both `visited` flag on each node and a `stack` are (worst case) *O*(*n*), remembering the last node is just *O*(1).

In C#, the algorithm could look like this:

```cs
static void Walk(Node node)
{
    Node lastNode = null;
    while (node != null)
    {
        if (lastNode == node.Parent)
        {
            if (node.Left != null)
            {
                lastNode = node;
                node = node.Left;
                continue;
            }
            else
                lastNode = null;
        }
        if (lastNode == node.Left)
        {
            Output(node);

            if (node.Right != null)
            {
                lastNode = node;
                node = node.Right;
                continue;
            }
            else
                lastNode = null;
        }
        if (lastNode == node.Right)
        {
            lastNode = node;
            node = node.Parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is in an infinite loop. When it tries to visit a leaf, after it comes up from the left side, the last node will be null, and when it intends to traverse down the right side, it will go into the (last == node.left) branch, and do the same thing all over again.

Comment: @Wilhelm No, it won't. Notice that the branch for the right side is in an `if`, not `else if`. So, After it comes up from the left side (in the `lastNode == node.Left` branch), it immediately looks at the right side (`lastNode == node.Right`) and only after that it loops over.

Comment: So you need a parent pointer, is it impossible to do otherwise then?

Comment: @bneil, you can also use a threaded tree. If you want to avoid the stack and the parent pointers.

Answer (score 14):

Here is another way to do it.  I think it is essentially equivalent to svick's answer, but avoids the extra variable.  This version is implemented in Python:

```py
node=root
if node is not None:
  while node.left is not None:
    node=node.left
  while node is not None:
    output(node)
    if node.right is not None:
      node=node.right
      while node.left is not None:
        node=node.left
    else:
      while node.parent is not None and node.parent.right is node:
        node=node.parent
      node=node.parent
```

Whatever node you visited last determines the next node that you need to visit.  If you've just visited node X, then you need to visit the left-most node to the right of X.  If X has no right child, then the next node is the first ancestor where node X didn't come from the right side.

Comment: The code that Vaughn Cato provided does indeed traverse the tree in order, but so far as I can tell, it runs in an infinite loop once it reaches the end of the tree. Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: @Nathan: I don't see the infinite loop you are talking about.  When it traverses to the right-most node, then the last loop should send it back to the root and finally set node to the parent of the root, which should be None.  The outer while loop would then terminate.

Comment: Nice and clean implementation +1

Comment: Tested a binary tree as root = 2, left = 1 and right = 3. It won't work and only output the left node.

Comment: @Patrick: I couldn't reproduce that issue.  It seems to work okay: http://codepad.org/njxp5tba

Comment: @VaughnCato Thanks for the response. I might get something wrong last night.

Answer (score 6):

Using [svick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41071/svick)'s correct idea (see his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371848/bst-in-order-traversal-iterative-parent-pointer-no-visited-flag-no-stack/10372118#10372118)), this is the *tested* code in C++. Note that I didn't test his code or even take a look at it, I just took his idea and implemented my own function.

```
void in_order_traversal_iterative_with_parent(node* root) {
node* current = root;
node* previous = NULL;

while (current) {
    if (previous == current->parent) { // Traversing down the tree.
        previous = current;
        if (current->left) {
            current = current->left;
        } else {
            cout << ' ' << current->data;
            if (current->right)
                current = current->right;
            else
                current = current->parent;
        }
    } else if (previous == current->left) { // Traversing up the tree from the left.
        previous = current;
        cout << ' ' << current->data;
        if (current->right)
            current = current->right;
        else
            current = current->parent;
    } else if (previous == current->right) { // Traversing up the tree from the right.
        previous = current;
        current = current->parent;
    }
}

cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void inorderNoStack() {
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }

    // use the previous to always track the last visited node
    // helps in deciding if we are going down/up
    Node prev = null;

    Node curr = root;

    while (curr != null) {
        // going down
        if (prev == null || prev.left == curr || prev.right == curr) {
            if (curr.left != null) {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr.left;
                continue;
            } else {

                visitn(curr);

                if (curr.right != null) {
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = curr.right;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    // swap states
                    prev = curr;
                    curr = prev.parent;
                }
            }
        }

        // going up after left traversal
        if (curr != null && prev == curr.left) {

            visitn(curr);

            if (curr.right != null) {
                prev = curr;
                curr = curr.right;
                continue;
            } else {
                // swap states
                prev = curr;
                curr = prev.parent;
            }
        }

        // going up after right traversal
        if (curr != null && prev == curr.right) {
            // swap states
            prev = curr;
            curr = prev.parent;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Answers containing just code with no explanation are not very useful.

Answer (score 0):

My Java solution without introducing any flag on the existing TREE. And no parent pointer as well. This approach will hold nodes up to the height of the tree. Please have a look.

https://github.com/skanagavelu/Algorithams/blob/master/src/tree/InOrderTraversalIterative.java

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : write a function which returns the in-order successor

Step 2 : Starting with the leftmost node, find the in-order successor until there is none

```
    public class TreeNode {
      int data;
      TreeNode left;
      TreeNode right;
      TreeNode parent;
    }

    public class TreeUtility {
      public void inorderNoRecursion(TreeNode root) {
        TreeNode current = leftmostNode(root);
        while(current != null) {
          System.out.println(current.data);
          current = inorderSuccessor(current);
        }
      }

      public TreeNode inorderSuccessor(TreeNode node) {
        if (node.right!=null) {
          return leftmostNode(node.right);
        }

        TreeNode p = node.parent;
        TreeNode c = node;
        while(p!=null && c != p.left) {
          c = p;
          p = p.parent;
        }
        return p;
      }

      private TreeNode leftmostNode(TreeNode node) {
        while (node.left != null) {
          node = node.left;
        }
        return node;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The key is the parent pointers (or the ability to mutate the tree), but you need a constant amount of extra state (e.g., the program counter of the following coroutine).

1. Set v to the root.
2. While v has a left child, set v to its left child.
3. Yield v.
4. If v is the root, then return.
5. Set p to v's parent.
6. If p's right child is v, then set v to p and go to step 4.
7. Yield p.
8. If p has a right child, then set v to p's right child and go to step 2.
9. Set v to p and go to step 4.

Comment: Your code fails too many test cases. I've translated it to the exact spaghetti code in C++ and ran it against my test suite.

Answer (score -2):

This is in C++:

```
void InOrder(Node *r)
{
   if(r==NULL)
         return;

   Node *t=r;

   while(t!=NULL)
       t=t->left;

  while(t!=r)
  {
     if(t==(t->parent->left))
     {
        cout<<t->parent->data;
        t=t->parent->right;
       if(t!=NULL)
      {
       while(t!=NULL)
          t=t->left;
      } 
      if(t==NULL)
          t=t->parent;
     }
     if(t==t->parent->right)
     {
        t=t->parent;
     }
  }
}
```